# JSdoc - Custom Type For Object Key For Autocompletion

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I wanted to get autocompletion on `AnimStore` for `AnimKey` (the key that gets the AnimLeaf).

`AnimKey` is user defined, so I can't create a list of possible strings.

```js
/**
 * @typedef {string} AnimKey
   having a non generic in the first element makes AnimStore any
 * @typedef {Object.<string, AnimLeaf>} AnimStore
 */
```

Is there a way to make `Object.<AnimKey, AnimLeaf>` work, or another way to get autocompletion for `AnimStore["this key"]`